# How do I check if I can use <sys/statvfs.h>?

Tags: c, portability, diskspace

I want to write a portable way to get the free disk space. On Windows, I use `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx`, and on Linux, the header `<sys/statvfs.h>` contains the function `statvfs64()` I can use.

My question is, on which systems I can assume that this header exists. Is there a macro I can check? Something like

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <windows.h>
#else
  #ifdef STATVFS_IS_AVAILABLE
  #include <sys/statvfs.h>
  #endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you would use autotools for stuff like that. `autoconf` creates a `config.h` header which defines a `HAVE_STATVFS` or so macro if you define a suitable configuration test.

However, due to the otherwise huge availability of `<sys/statvfs.h>`, you can also less portably simply test for `_MSC_VER`, as you just did.

Comment: `sys/statvfs` is [standard POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/sys/statvfs.h.html), so it's pretty portable.  Microsoft is more the outlier in this case.